# AOS(Animation On Scroll) Library doesn't work with SmoothScrollbar-js

Tags: html, smooth-scrolling, aos.js

I'm using [SmoothScrollbar](https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/)  Library and [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) in my HTML website. But AOS animation is not working. Below is my JS code:

```js
// ====== SMOOTH SCROLL ======
var Scrollbar = window.Scrollbar;
  Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('#smooth_scrollbar'), {
    damping: 0.05,          // Controls the damping effect
    alwaysShowTracks: true, // Always show scrollbar tracks
});


// ==== AOS ANIMATION ====
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        AOS.init({
            offset: 120,
        });
    }, 120);
    // AOS.init();
})
```

When I remove the Smooth Scroll code, AOS works fine. Please help!

As I checked the code in Inspect, **aos-animate** class is not adding. Here is Screenshot: [image: Inspect Screenshot]

Comment: Hey! did you get any solution ? I am also stuck.